# Give edit permission to "Everyone" in SharePoint list using PowerShell Client side code

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have created a list in SharePoint site using PowerShell client side code. Now I want to edit the permission for this list. I want to give edit permission for this list to `Everyone`. This is how I am getting the `Everyone` detail:

```
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$user  =$Ctx.web.EnsureUser("c:0(.s|true")
$Ctx.Load($user)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

And to break the inheritance of the list I used this:

```
$List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName")
$Ctx.Load($List)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$List.BreakRoleInheritance($true)
```

But I am not sure how to give edit permission for this list to `Everyone`. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample on how to grant `Edit` permissions to principal per List:

```
$roleDefinition = $ctx.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]::Editor)  
$roleBindings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx) 
$roleBindings.Add($roleDefinition)
$ctx.Load($list.RoleAssignments.Add($user, $roleBindings))
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

**Prerequisites**

[SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any dll dependency for this? If yes then how can check whether the dll is loaded or not? Because sometimes the `$user` is coming as blank.

Comment: @HarshJaswal, there is a dependency to [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Comment: Thanks for the help.